# Staging Wordpress shows 404 for WooCommerce Products & Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress site with Woocommerce.  For the past years, I have been creating staging environment through Softaculous interface, do the updates in my staging environment and then push them to the live site.

However, recently I came across an issue with WooCommerce products and I can't seem to find a way to fix it.  Basically when I add a new product to WooCommerce and try to preview it on the staging site, I get a 404 No Results Found.  The product category pages are also not working and some of the pages are redirecting me to the live site.

I have:

1. tried creating a new staging site in case something went wrong
2. disabled all plugins except WooCommerce
3. updating permalinks in case something went wrong
4. confirmed that the URL
5. verified that the wp-config is correct for staging environment
6. confirmed with hosting company that requests are hitting the correct database, though there are no other logs from their end
7. have purged cloudflare cache and also enabled development mode after just in case

All the above however have not fixed the issue and at this point I am pretty much clueless at what might be the issue. Is there anything else that I should look for or anyone ever encountered this issue?

*Edit*:  I am on the latest versions of WordPress and WooCommerce.  All other plugins are up to date as well (though disabled at this point).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the root culprit which was leading to this behaviour.
The SSL certificate had expired and hence when you try to load the staging site, Cloudflare was redirecting me to the live site.

Once the SSL was renewed, all started working fine as before.